# How to pass parameter from android native app into swf file

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe

I have an swf file in my asset folder and I am able to show up its content on native using Adobe AIR. Now I need to pass parameter (source)dynamically from my android native app into that swf file so it can show up different content. How can I pass parameter from android into swf file.

Thanks.

Comment: **1.** How are you showing up content of swf from native app? **2.** Have you tried embedding swf in HTML and passing variables from there?

Comment: nope..i used Adobe AIR for showing swf content on native app.but i need to pass dynamic values into swf.Thats my prob.

Comment: So, you have been showing *swf* file from ActionScript (using *Adobe AIR*) and now you want to do the same from Java?

Answer (score 0):

You could create HTML code that would load you swf file. Then put that HTML into `WebView` to display. Passing parameters would be done exactly as you would do in a web page.

Some sample code, that should get you going:

```
String htmlSource = "<object type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" data=\"file:///android_asset/yourFile.swf\" width=\"360\" height=\"280\">
                 <param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///android_asset/yourFile.swf\" />
                 <param name=\"source\" value=\"valueForSourceParam\" />
                 <param name=\"someOtherParam\" value=\"valueForSomeOtherParam\" />
               </object>";

    WebView webView= new WebView(this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlSource, "text/html, "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: Yeah i agree.But if i use this code.,it will display the swf content only on browser not as native app.I need to show up its content natively

Comment: Does that swf use Flex/AIR or some other library/technology that would make it 'native'?

Comment: Yeah i use AIR to make it as native.But i need to pass values from android application into swf dynamically..for ex.swf content might be video player means.,i need to pass video url's from my android native app.

Comment: You could [package your swf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac25d3d8c712b2d86751e-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac25d3d8c712b2d86751e-7ffb) as (separate) native Android app using Adobe AIR. Then you could communicate with that app using your own `Intent`s.